# Is there a word for the tangible equivalent of visualization?

Tags: single-word-requests, neologisms

The word *visualization* is often used to describe an image or interactive piece of media that represents a data set. I am trying to think if there is an equivalent for something that is not only visual, but also tangible. That is, an object that represents data and that people can touch and see. If there is no word for this, can you think of a neologism for it e.g."tangiblelization"?

EDIT: By tangible I mean an object that can you can youch with your hands.

Comment: Not sure, but what you're describing is almost *virtual reality* (VR).

Comment: _Virtual reality_ is quite vague; it means, roughly, 'close enough to fool some people'. You want something that specifically addresses the tactile sense, right? Using the hands and eyes simultaneously?

Comment: Wouldn't that simply be a _model_?

Comment: The words *tangibilization* and *tangibilize* (note spelling) have a few hits on Google but don't seem to appear in many dictionaries.

Comment: That is usually called a *prototype*. Still not a finished product and very much still a part of the visualisation process. It may or may not be tangible depending upon the delivery medium of the product, cost of the project and is usually made for the sake of usability studies in order to refine the prototype more before finally entering the development phase.

Comment: In a comment below, you said that it must be **something you CANNOT experience through a computer screen, but rather you must touch to experience**. That changes the question significantly. The answer is a model, be it architectural or a prototype of a manufactured product. Realization is good too. There are many good answers here.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a perfect fit, but many of the suggestions should work well if you don't mind using an adjective instead of a noun. Two more relevant words are _tactile_ and _haptic_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make something tangible is to make it real; *[realize](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=realize)* is the usual term for this process, so *[realization](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=realization)* would describe making an abstract dataset into something real.

> A 3D printer allows the *realization* of abstract mathematical
>   surfaces in polycarbonate.

Comment: Thanks. That seems really accurate. However, the term "realization" probably wouldn't be as obvious as visualization. I do think a new term might be necessary. The definition of the term would certainly use the term realization.

Answer (score 3):

Some words usually adduced for such meaning are:
• *[embodiment](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/embodiment#Noun)* (“a physical entity typifying an abstraction”),
•  *[incarnation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/incarnation#Noun)* (“A person or thing regarded as embodying or exhibiting some quality, idea, or the like”),
•  *[manifestation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/manifestation#Noun)* (“”The embodiment of an intangible, or variable thing), and
•  *[reification](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reification#Noun)*, of which  [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification) says: “Reification generally refers to making something real, bringing it into being, or making something concrete. ...” 
Note, some people are allergic to the word *reification* (ie, will harshly criticize its use in almost any context) so do not use it widely or generally.

Answer (score 3):

Corporealization - to give physical form to.  Not very often used, but it is a real word.

Answer (score 1):

That is usually called a *prototype*. It is still not a finished product and very much a part of the visualisation process. It may or may not be tangible depending upon the delivery medium of the product, cost of the project and is usually made for the sake of usability studies in order to refine the product more before finally entering the development phase.

Answer (score 1):

In the teaching profession where the use of tangible objects as teaching aids is common these are often referred to as [***manipulables***](http://books.google.com/books?id=q90BpBRBsjoC&pg=PA5&dq=%22use+of+manipulables%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZKfwUP-eAaLqiwLwkYDYAg&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22use%20of%20manipulables%22&f=false)

Comment: Good point. Like Montessori's. Still, I'm looking for something more technologically sounding.

Answer (score 0):

I would think it would be perceptualization. (Although my computer doesn't recognize the spelling) As something that is tangible is something that can be perceived. Although I don't understand what you meant by "visual but also tangible"... Would not anything tangible be visible?

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/perceptualize

Comment: You're right. Everything tangible would be visible. I meant that I am referring to something you cannot experience through a computer screen, but rather that you have to touch to experience.

Answer (score 0):

How about the [fleshing out](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flesh+out) of a visual idea?

**flesh out**: to give substance to

Answer (score 0):

In computing science it has become common to talk about [haptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haptics) interfaces, which engage the sense of touch.  You could be the first kid on the block to use **haptize**.